# How can I fetch data from an HTTPS Url via Proxy?

Tags: java, sockets, ssl, proxy

I am getting `Connection timed out: connect`.

My code:

```
    System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "proxy.mycompany.com");
    System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "8080");

    String url = URL_BASE + "&limit=5";
    URL u = new URL(url);
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(
            u.openStream()));

    String inputLine;

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
        System.out.println(inputLine);

    in.close();
```

Comment: check if you proxy server needs authentication then pass username/password.

Comment: The proxy server does not need authentication.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're fetching a URL on HTTPS, then you must set `https.proxyHost` and `https.proxyPort`. See documentation on [Java Networking and Proxies](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/net/proxies.html), section 2.2.

```
System.setProperty("https.proxyHost", "proxy.mycompany.com");
System.setProperty("https.proxyPort", "8080");
```

assuming that `proxy.mycompany.com` on port `8080` is also an HTTPS proxy

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you fetch the content using [apache http commons httpclient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/index.html). There you can set proxy authentication on the client without the need to modify the global jvm properties.